# osig file TextClipping causes error during attempted build Mac OS X desktop el capitan

Tags: android, macos, gear-vr

Unity program built on desktop MAC works on MAC
During build for Galaxy S7/GearVR the sig file is not accepted.  Error as below:
CommandInvokationFailure: Android Asset Packaging Tool failed.
/Users/rpantera/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt package -v -f -F assets.ap_ -A assets --ignore-assets "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"

stderr[
assets/-Ï÷R1ë ¡BB0ó R-ö--tœ∂®- -`”.textClipping: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.
]
stdout[
Found 35 custom asset files in assets
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg, Int32 retriesOnFailure)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Any reason for textClipping?
How to fix?